# How to parameterize a circle by arclength using polar coordinates with the center offset from the origin?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I ran into this while attempting to draw points on a circle using polar coordinates with the origin offset from the center of the circle.

The objective is to find a closed form expression for the length of the segment labled $a$ as a function of the angle $\alpha.$ The radius $R$ is fixed, as is the distance $c$ from $\mathfrak{C}$ to $\mathfrak{c}$. Since we have two fixed sides and an angle for the triangle $\mathfrak{cCP},$ the value of $a$ is, in principle, determined. Using the law of cosines, the following two equations are easily established:

$$R^{2}=a^{2}+c^{2}+2ca\cos\left(\alpha\right)$$

$$a=\sqrt{c^{2}+R^{2}-2cR\cos\left(\rho\right)}$$

In the first of these we have both $a$ and $a^{2}.$ In the second, the value of $\rho$has not been given.

When I started trying to figure this out, it seemed straight-forward. But all I have managed to accomplish is to find new and interesting ways to derive the law of cosines.

How might we express a as a function of $\alpha?$

[image]

This is a response to a follow-up challenge in the answer.

[image]

This is a second attempt at the follow-up.

[image]

This is what motivated the original question.  It's J.J. Thomson method of illustrating why the field strength of EM radiation falls off as the first power of the inverse of distance from the source, but Coulomb's law gives field strength as the inverse squared distance.  The field line density is increased in the perturbed region.  The the increase fall off as $\frac{1}{r}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By law of cosines, $$
R^2 = c^2 + a^2 -2ac \cos(\pi-\alpha)
$$
so
\begin{align}
0 &= a^2 -a\left(2c \cos(\pi-\alpha)\right) + (c^2 - R^2)
\end{align}
which is a quadratic in $a$, with solutions
\begin{align}
a 
&= \frac{\left(2c \cos(\pi-\alpha)\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(2c \cos(\pi-\alpha)\right)^2 - 4(c^2 - R^2) }}{2}\\
&= \frac{\left(-2c \cos(\alpha)\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(2c \cos(\alpha)\right)^2 - 4(c^2 - R^2) }}{2}\\
&= \left(-c \cos(\alpha)\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(c \cos(\alpha)\right)^2 - (c^2 - R^2) }\\
\end{align}

I'll let you try to work out geometrically what the second solution might correspond to. Hint: extend the red arrow.

Comment: As soon as I posted, I realized that I needed the quadratic formula.

Comment: Please see what I added to the question.  Does that address what you were getting at?

Comment: I don't think so, because those two $a$ lengths are the same, while the algebra gives two DIFFERENT numbers.If, in your first diagram, you "extend the red arrow" until you hit the circle in the lower semi-circle, you get another point with the same alpha (or at least the same *cosine*), same R, same c, but a different $a$ (I believe).

Comment: OK, I wasn't trying to get both answers.  The illustration was just what came to mind immediately.  I posted a new graphic which I believe illustrates your intent.

Comment: I understood that; I merely wanted to say that in general when something comes of quadratic, there are two solutions, usually for a reason (like "there's a second point satisfying the same geometric conditions you specified"). Sometimes it's totally spurious, but more often than not, I find that the source of the second solution gives me a kind of heads-up that's useful.

Comment: I guess I could feel embarrassed that I even posted the question.  As I wrote the bit about having a to the first and second power, I considered "completing the square", but decided to post before I spent more time on the problem.  I'm glad I posted it.  I gained insight I would never have gotten on my own.  I have to say, it seems like a good problem for a trig course.  Not only is it tricky, its solution leads to significant insight.

Comment: I think that posting questions that lead to insight, even if you could have solved them yourself, is *great*. As it happened, the insight went the other direction too: I'd seen that Thompson diagram in the past, and just slid right past it without understanding, and this made me look and think again.